# Is it possible to write on an external socket using Guzzle?

Tags: php, sockets, curl, stream, guzzle

Here is my usecase, I want to convert this PHP code:

```
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'local_cert' => $myLocalCert,
            'passphrase' => $myPassphrase,
        ),
    ));
    $stream = stream_socket_client(
        'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',
        $errno,
        $errstr,
        30,
        STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,
        $ctx
    );

    fwrite($stream, $myMessage, strlen($myMessage));
```

to something similar using the great [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) lib.

I know that Guzzle has a Stream class, that we can send as "body" of a request, but I don't even know if Guzzle allows to use another protocol than "http(s)"...

Any Guzzle experts here? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supporting custom protocols seems out of scope for an HTTP client like Guzzle.

Are you sending HTTP messages to that endpoint? If so, why can't you use https? If not, what features of Guzzle do you want to use? Most of the library is very HTTP-specific.

Comment: No, it's clearly not HTTP message. Ok, I just thought that Guzzle Stream object would help.

Comment: I think you just want a generic stream wrapper. You can save the overhead of loading Guzzle and just write [a small class](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) to handle your protocol